# Doble loop en una list comprehension? (lista de diccionarios)

Tags: python, lista, python-3.7

Supongamos que tengo la siguiente lista de diccionarios:

```
content = [
           {'Id': 2424,
            'Seasons':[
                      {'Id': 323},
                      {'Id': 245}
                     ]
            }, 
            {'Id': 2424,
             'Seasons':[
                      {'Id': 323},
                      {'Id': 245}
                     ]
            }
           ]
```

Como iteraria sobre el campo seasons de cada contenido en la lista para extraer los id de cada season? mediante list comprenhension

Comment: Que has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: Un loop tradicional: for c in content: for season in c['Seasons']: evaluar..., la idea es tratar de hacerlo mediante list comprenhension

Comment: Por favor añadelo para ver que es lo que buscas, quieres generar una nueva lista que contenga las Id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haber vamos por partes, una compresión de lista o *list comprehension* es un ciclo `for` abreviado, por lo que podemos realizar lo mismo que con el ciclo `for` normal. Lo que tratas de hacer es una *compresión de lista anidada* (igual que los ciclos for anidados).

Veamos un pequeño ejemplo:

```py
unaLista = [10,20,30,40,50]
otraLista = [1,2,3,4,5]

lista = [(x,y) for x in unaLista for y in otraLista]
print(lista)
```

Aquí iteramos en `otraLista` generando la variable `y`, luego en cada una de esa iteración vamos a iterar en la lista `unaLista` generando la variable `x` y luego devolvemos una tupla `(x,y)`, teniendo como resultado:

```py
[(10, 1), (10, 2), (10, 3), (10, 4), (10, 5), 
(20, 1), (20, 2), (20, 3), (20, 4), (20, 5), 
(30, 1), (30, 2), (30, 3), (30, 4), (30, 5), 
(40, 1), (40, 2), (40, 3), (40, 4), (40, 5), 
(50, 1), (50, 2), (50, 3), (50, 4), (50, 5)]
```

Que es lo mismo que hacer:

```py
lista = []
for x in unaLista:
    for y in otraLista:
        lista.append((x,y))

print(lista)
```

Ahora para tu problema vamos a iterar en `content[0]['Seasons']` y luego tendremos que iterar en en una posición `i` de `content[0]['Seasons'][i]['Id']`para acceder directamente al valor del `Id`, para eso iteraremos en un rango, que sera la longitud de `content[0]['Seasons']`

```py
ids = [content[0]['Seasons'][i]['Id'] for x in content[0]['Seasons'] for i in range(len(content[0]['Seasons']))]

print(ids)
```

**Resultado**

```
[323, 245, 323, 245]
```

Si reemplazamos `content[0]['Seasons'][i]['Id']` por `x` nos dará `{'Id': 323}` por eso utilizamos la variable `i` para acceder al elemento. También podemos evitar los elementos repetidos, solo hace falta poner un condicional

Comment: Muy util, me sirvio! gracias

Answer (score 0):

Dado que la comprobación de los resultados es complicada al ser iguales te propongo unos que permitan que se compruebe el paso por todas las ramas de los diccionarios.

```
content = [
            {'Id': 2424,
             'Seasons': [ {'Id': 323}, {'Id': 245} ]
             },
            {'Id': 2425,
             'Seasons': [ {'Id': 423}, {'Id': 345} ]
             }
           ]
```

Como me cuesta bastante aún las comprensiones de listas pienso que si lo hicieramos con varios for sería algo así como esto:

```
ids = []

for x in content:
    for i in (x['Seasons']):
        ids.append(i['Id'])
```

y trasladado al objetivo:

```
ids = [i['Id'] for x in content for i in x['Seasons']]
print(*ids)
```

El resultado

```
323 245 423 345
```