# ¿Cómo comprimo un ciclo for del siguiente código?

Tags: python, bucle-for

Anteriormente había preguntado sobre la comprensión de listas y varias personas me explicaron muy bien las diferentes formas de comprimir las listas y algunas colecciones. Ahora me encuentro con un problema similar, en donde se aplica específicamente una comprensión de listas.

Tengo el siguiente código, trato de iterar un numero aleatorio que muestre sus tablas de multiplicar. Con el primer ciclo **for** arroje la cantidad de iteraciones que el usuario elija y los número salgan al azar, y con otro ciclo **for**, me permita elegir la longitud de las tablas de multiplicar por cada número.

El problema viene que no se puede llamar la variable **"x"** ("x" es el número aleatorio), que está en el primer ciclo, en en el segundo ciclo, para eso, lógicamente se debe crear el primer ciclo for y en el segundo se debe comprimir.

```
for j in range(iteraciones):
    x=randint(1, 100)
    print(x)

    for i in range(1, insert+1):
        n=x*i
        print(n)
```

Trato de hacer esto:

```
for j in range(iteraciones):
    x=randint(1, 100)
    print(x)

    print(s for s in range(1, insert+1) if (x>0): n=x*1)
```

Pero, no consigo que funcione. En este caso, ¿qué debo hacer para resolver este problema?
De antemano, agradezco mucho su ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: Tal vez te pueda servir esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/459588/183782)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veo que todavía eres nuevo con las comprensiones. Primero que nada, en los condicionales no se agregan los `:` ni se escribe que hacer. Además, en tú código no estás imprimiendo los valores, sino que estás creando un generador con los valores e imprimes el generador.

Una forma sencilla de hacer lo que quieres sería esta:

```
for j in range(iteraciones):
    x=randint(1, 100)
    print(f"\nNumber: {x}")

    [print(f"{x} x {i} = {x*i}") for i in range(1, insert+1)]
```

La comprensión la hago entre corchetes, y solamente le digo que imprima x * i para cada i.

Ahora bien, técnicamente puedes hacer todo en una linea, pero no lo recomiendo porque la lectura se dificulta. Aun así te la dejo por si te interesa.

```
[(print(f"\nNumber: {x}") if i == 1 else None,print(f"{x} x {i} = {x*i}")) for j in range(iterations) if (x := randint(1,100)) for i in range(1, insert+1)]
```

Veámoslo de a poco. Al principio tenemos 2 expresiones en una tupla, la primera imprime el número cuando `i == 1`, para esto uso un operador ternario de la forma `caso_verdadero if condicion else caso_falso`, reemplazando queda `print("\nNumber: " + str(x)) if i == 1 else None`. La segunda parte de la tupla imprime `x*i`, para eso formateo una cadena colocando la 'f' al principio `print(f"{x} x {i} = " + str(x*i))`. Luego de la tupla está el primer `for`, en este pasamos como parámetro las iteraciones `for j in range(iterations)`. Justo después del primer `for` tenemos la sentencia `if (x := randint(1,100))`, esto lo que hace es definir una variable local utilizando el operador de asignación de expresión `:=`, disponible desde la versión 3.8 de python. Y finalmente el segundo `for` donde pasamos `insert`, `for i in range(1, insert+1)`.

Comment: Puedes usar `{x*i}` dentro del f-string y te ahorras el `str`  y la concatenación. Igual al imprimir `\nNumber`

Comment: Muy cierto, respuesta editada

Comment: Muchas gracias!